# Android Wear Launcher

Tags: android, wear-os, android-launcher

I am wondering how the Android Wear launchers like Swipify and Wear Mini Launcher **intercept touch events on the android wear home screen**.

I have tried adding the onTouch and onClick listeners to the Watch View Stub in my app so far, but I can not figure out how to get touches that occur outside of my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the views are directly added in the `WindowManager` in a `Service`.
You can take a look at this thread to understand how it works: [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

Be careful, there is an issue in the Moto 360 system at this time as explained here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/113671876130843889747/posts/9bqUcdgZnNb
You will have to use the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR` flag to avoid the bottom space. By the way, you can also take a look at the code I gave in this post to understand how overlaying works. Direct link: https://github.com/PomepuyN/WatchviewStubIssue

Comment: Hi Nicolas, do you think that you could help me here? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496768/android-wear-overlay-pass-on-touch-events