# Android wear custom launcher

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Does anyone know how the Android wear mini laucher is implemented?

How do these things work:
- Start the launcher from watch face by swiping Form left upper corner
- get all wearable apps 
- Start a wearable APP

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of a previous here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042943/android-wear-launcher